# JSON objects returning "@" with field name. Is this a bug or a feature?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jersey

I have a simple REST web service that uses Jersey version 11 (1.11). When I request the data in JSON, I get a response similar to this:

```
{
    "@course_name": "test1",
    "@cid": "testMike",
    "@start_date": "2012-03-13T00:00:00.000-04:00",
    "@end_date": "2012-03-20T00:00:00.000-04:00",
    "@row_id": "testMike"
},
```

Can anyone tell me why the "@" is appearing on each `key:value` pair?

Comment: You may need to provide more details; that doesn't happen for me.

Comment: You kind of need to provide info on what exactly is producing the response...lang, program, framework, etc... some code would be helpful.

Comment: You should add the code for your entity so we can help you better. Are you using @XmlAttribute by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you're labelling the fields in your Java classes as XML attributes (with `@XmlAttribute` annotations), not XML elements (with `@XmlElement` annotations).

Search for "@XmlAttribute" in this document: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html

Comment: Thank you for the link.  Its not a bug, but a feature of JAXB with Json.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  It was very helpful.  Its not a bug but a feature of JAXB with Json.  If you use attribute instead of element in your XSD, you will get "@" pre-pended to your field names.  There are work arounds using "attributesAsElements".  However, the simple fix was to change my XSD to use elements instead of attributes.